# Creating button with gradients in CSS

Tags: html, css, button, gradient

What i am trying to achieve is simple. A client wants this button:

http://i59.tinypic.com/207b56p.png

provided in the design PSDs replicated in html. I have been playing around with different gradients and such and have only been able to achieve this:

```
     background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#FEC1F4), to(#FF2DFF));
     background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #FEC1F4, #FF2DFF);
     background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #FEC1F4, #FF2DFF);
     background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #FEC1F4, #FF2DFF);
     background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #FEC1F4, #FF2DFF);
     background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #FEC1F4, #FF2DFF);filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,startColorstr=#FEC1F4, endColorstr=#FF2DFF);
```

which is by far not even close.

1. Is there a way to make this button with gradients in CSS or not?
2. If theres not what is the proper way to use images as button backgrounds in HTML? Because not all buttons are the same size and an image background might be distorted in places. (Any best practices?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do it like this:

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4qfhk0bg/)

```css
body {
    margin: 50px;
}
div {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
    height: 50px;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to bottom, #FF5EFF 0%, #FF5EFF 50%, #FF2DFF 51%, #FF2DFF 100%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(to bottom, #FF5EFF 0%, #FF5EFF 50%, #FF2DFF 51%, #FF2DFF 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(to bottom, #FF5EFF 0%, #FF5EFF 50%, #FF2DFF 51%, #FF2DFF 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(to bottom, #FF5EFF 0%, #FF5EFF 50%, #FF2DFF 51%, #FF2DFF 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #FF5EFF 0%, #FF5EFF 50%, #FF2DFF 51%, #FF2DFF 100%);
}
div:before, div:after {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 36px;
    width: 36px;
    margin-left: -36px;
    transform-origin: 100% 100%;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    background: #FEC1F4;
}
div:before {
    left: 0;
}
div:after {
    right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

*Side note: You may need to change the colors.

Comment: Great solution using CSS 3 selector :before and :after!

Comment: This worked! Thanks a lot! I hope to be as good at this one day as you are :) Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Solution without using CSS 3:

Use background-image in order to recreate the 3D effect inside the button.

Use box-shadow in order to create the shadow effect around the button.

Just a quick example how your code would be:

```
   .btn{
        width:100px;
        height: 50px;
        background-image: url('image.png');
        background-color: #cccccc;

       -moz-box-shadow:    3px 3px 5px 6px #ccc;
       -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px 6px #ccc;
        box-shadow:         3px 3px 5px 6px #ccc;
    }
```

If you need to reuse your button with on different size inside your website, you can slice your PSD button in three parts (look image attached), HTML would be something like this.

```
<div class="btn">
<div class="left">
</div>
<div class="center">
</div>
<div class="right">
</div>
```

You can set the widht of `.center` as percentage and .left and .right with fixed sizes and background images.

[image]

Comment: Mary Melody's solutions is great approach with CSS3